# Conjugacy groups in compact Lie groups are compact embedded submanifolds

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, lie-groups, compactness, submanifold

Show that for any subgroup H < G where G is a compact Lie-group, the conjugacy groups $\{gHg^{-1} |\: g \in G\}$ form compact embedded submanifolds.

My ideas:
I am wondering whether "H is closed" is needed as an assumption. Because then we would have since the conjugation-action is a diffeomorphism, that any conjugacy-group is also closed. And as a subspace of G therefore compact.

If H would be closed, then since the conjugation-action $x \mapsto g \cdot x \cdot g^{-1}$ is a homeomorphism, its image is also closed in G. It is easy to verify, that $\{ghg^-1 | h \in H\}$ satisfies the group axioms for any $g \in G$. And by the closed-subgroup theorem, it would therefore be an embedded submanifold.

But I cannot find a way to solve this without H closed. If anyone has an idea whether that would work that would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Are you really asking whether the **conjugacy class** of $H$ is a compact embedded submanifold? It seems you are instead asking whether each individual conjugate subgroup $g H g^{-1}$ is a compact embedded submanifold.

Comment: Oh thank you @LeeMosher. That was the source of my confusion and why I couldn't get the exercise right. I think it's best if I reformulate the question to "conjugate group" since it is interesting on its own. If  I still can't solve the exercise I will open a new thread